# Facebook Share OG tags error

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

On this page https://www.morph.org/ramanujan.html the Share post button is not working properly. Checked all the OP tags and they look fine, but the FB validator is saying the title tag is missing a string - which it is not. The image, title, and description is not showing up in the share button at the bottom of the page.

Search all over the web - couldn't find a reason for this issue. Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix your SSL issue.

Second, you need to fix your HTML http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.morph.org%2Framanujan.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Lastly, make sure your og:url matches the requested URL.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the reply. On the SSL issue - I am not sure what I am supposed to fix? The https:// is resolving ok. But the FB validator gives me this error: Curl Error : SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.morph.org' and on the og:url - is is the same as the requested URL as noted in first message.